# ls discrepancy with du df output

Tags: command-line, filesystem, disk-usage, embedded-system

Adding up the sizes of files and directories returned by `ls` gives a different value than that given by `df` or `du`. The `df` and `du` commands give me the same output, so I don't have that frequent problem, but I know that this was an "empty" device/folder so I wanted to know why that "not empty" used space.

My first thought was about hidden files, so I searched around and I found the -a option but the figures don't add up yet [24.4 KB from `ls -lah` is very different from 5.1 MB with df and du: output at the end of the message]. Another strange thing is the e2fsck output, seems like there are 13 files [., .., lost+found, but how to find the remaining 10?]

Does somebody know what I'm still missing?

---

```
cd /mnt

# ls -lah
total 24
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root       20.0K May  7 09:36 .
drwxrwxr-x   17 root     root         420 May  7 09:26 ..
drwx------    2 root     root        4.0K Apr 21 13:42 lost+found


# df -h /mnt
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
mmcblk0p1                 1.8G      5.1M      1.7G   0% /mnt


# du -d 0 -h /mnt
5.1M    /mnt


# umount /mnt
# e2fsck -C 0 /dev/mmcblk0p1
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/mmcblk0p1: clean, 13/117360 files, 8693/468990 blocks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls` doesn't show the size of a directory's contents. It shows the size used to store the metadata describing the directory. That size will depend on the number of files in the directory and the length of their (and the directory's) names, and not on their sizes. To illustrate, I will create different numbers of empty (0-size) files:

```
## 10 files
for i in {1..10}; do touch foo/$i; done
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 May 11 16:36 foo
$ du -sc foo/* | grep total
0   total

## 100000 files
$ touch foo/file{1..100000}
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 2801664 May 11 16:37 foo
$ du -sc foo/* | grep total
0   total
```

As you can see above, the size reported by `ls` changed, despite the actual size of the directory being the same.

So, your missing files are probably in the `lost+found` directory, check there.